# PhoneGap/Cordova upgrade to latest version application stop working

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have upgraded my android application from phonegap version 3 to version 5 and application stoped working my jQuery not working anymore.

my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/cordova.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", loginWithuuid, false);
function loginWithuuid() {
    var usr = window.localStorage["user_id"];
    if(usr == "")
    {
        $("#voucher").hide();
    }
}
function openDeviceBrowser(externalLinkToOpen)
{
    window.open(externalLinkToOpen, '_system', 'location=no');
}
</script>
<script>
    var serviceURL = "http://<web>.com/API/";
    function loginNow() {
        navigator.notification.activityStart("Wait","Authenticating....");
        var email       = $('#contactEmailField').val();
        var password       = $('#contactPasswordField').val();
        $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'androidapi.php?email='+email+'&password='+encodeURIComponent(password)+'&action=login', function(data) {
        if(data.result == 1){
            window.localStorage["user_id"] = data.login;
            window.localStorage["user_name"] = data.name;
            navigator.notification.activityStop();
            window.location="home.html";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            navigator.notification.activityStop();
            alert(data.message);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

This code work perfect before update and now its not working.

Comment: also am interested in your project ,don`t know if you can post your project source code here ,will be glad if you  do so.

Comment: how did you upgrade? did you install whitelist plugin? did you configure whitelist plugin? do you have a Content Security Policy meta tag?

Comment: No i didn't add any whitelist can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`charset="utf-8"` sometimes may not make it work. Instead, use it without.

Your code should be like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That should work for you.